# Why is there a little padding at bottom of my UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

UPDATE 1: I have confirmed that this is NOT the footer.

Here is what it looks like. Notice the small space below the last cell. Also shown in the picture, the scroll IS at the proper spot:
[image]

Here are the settings of the view controller:
[image]

Comment: I am not mobile developer, but I found this article below... Did you check the constraints? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650668/swift-why-scrollview-not-full-screen/37651742#37651742

Comment: Nothing to do with constraints. You might have implemented a footer in your tableview

Comment: `- (CGFloat)heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section { return 0.00001; };` is needed for tableViews with the `group` style.

Comment: @Brandon I have confirmed that this is NOT the footer.

Comment: try setting adjust scroll view insets = true. In story board just check  adjust scroll view insets. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set adjust scroll view insets to true.

[image]